# Model method that depends on DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

## Context

I have a model for representing comments that looks like the following:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CommentId { get; set; } // Id of parent comment
    ...
}
```

In my `DetailsModel` class which is a subclass of `PageModel`, I have the following method for finding replies to a given comment:

```
    public IList<Comment> Replies(int comment_id) =>
        _context.Comment.Where(comment => comment.CommentId == comment_id).ToListAsync().Result;
```

I use it from a Razor page as follows:

```
Model.Replies(reply.Id).Count
```

This works fine.

## More object-oriented approach?

In a more traditional object-oriented design, `Replies` might be a method on `Comment`. So finding the replies would look like this:

```
reply.Replies()
```

Moving the `Replies` method into `Comment`, we get:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CommentId { get; set; } // Id of parent comment
    ...

    public async Task<IList<Comment>> Replies()
    {
        return await _context.Comment.Where(comment => comment.CommentId == Id).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

And now you can see the issue; `Comment` now has a dependency on the `DbContext`, which seems like a very odd arrangement.

So my question is, is there a way to get `Replies` to be a method on `Comment` in a way that's idiomatic for ASP.NET Core / EF Core?

## UPDATE - CommentAlt

Here's one approach I've explored.

- I have a `CommentAlt` class.
- It is a subclass of `Comment` (so as to inherit all the fields from `Comment`).
- The constructor accepts a `BasePageModel`.
- My page models inherit from `BasePageModel`.
- `BasePageModel` gives `CommentAlt` access to things like

  - `DbContext`
  - `UserManager<IdentityUser>`
  - `AuthorizationService`

Here's `CommentAlt`:

```cs
    public class CommentAlt : Comment
    {
        private BasePageModel Model { get; }

        public CommentAlt(Comment comment, BasePageModel model)
        {
            Id = comment.Id;
            CommentId = comment.CommentId;
            ...

            Model = model;
        }

        public IList<CommentAlt> Replies() =>
            Model.Context.Comment
                .Where(comment => comment.CommentId == Id).ToList()
                .Select(elt => new CommentAlt(elt, Model)).ToList();
        
        ...
    }
```

As you can see, now `Replies` is a method on it. In one of my Razor pages, I have the following expression:

```
@if (reply.Replies().Count > 0)
```

and it works fine.

Here's my `BasePageModel` which is passed to the `CommentAlt` contructor:

```cs
    public class BasePageModel : PageModel
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
        public IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService { get; }
        public UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; }

        public BasePageModel(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager) : base()
        {
            Context = context;
            UserManager = userManager;
            AuthorizationService = authorizationService;
        }
    }
```

One thing I feel a little weird about is having the `Context`, `AuthorizationService`, and `UserManager` properties here be `public`. I changed them to public so that `ConmmentAlt` would have access to them.

Is the approach taken here with `CommentAlt` recommended? Is there a better way?

Comment: I would not try to make it OOP this way. Some ones always think that class must be OOP with behaviors. But I think there is a special type of class in which it just contains ***data***, like a mug containing water. The mug itself cannot produce water to be contained by it. We need some other external service to put water in it. I don't see anything wrong with classes containing just data. It can contain behaviors but they should act on the loaded data (not loading data by itself). View models in asp.net are typical examples of classes containing just data and loaded by other services.

Comment: in this case your `Comment` just need to expose a (maybe readonly) property of `Replies` containing all loaded replies which are prepared by other external service (like a view model loader). Actually this view model usually exposes just ***top*** replies because in reality, we may have thousands of replies and loading them all into the `Comment` model is just not right & performant.

Comment: putting data into an object itself is a behavior. If you want it OOP, you can declare your operation method in which the `Replies` property is set. So because the data is taken from some source, so that source must be a parameter of that operation, e.g: `Comment.LoadReplies(DbContext source)`. You can even abstract that parameter so that it looks like a real data source for replies (not just from `DbContext` directly).

Comment: @KingKing I would consider exploring the `LoadReplies` approach that you mention. However, the Razor Page would need access to the `DbContext`, which in turn means that `DetailsModel` would have to expose it. Is this a normal thing to do? I.e. have a Razor Page access a `DbContext`?

Comment: actually you should call that `LoadReplies` in the `PageModel` derived class (or in controller action). That's the phase the view model is prepared. You can inject `DbContext` in Razor Page (using `@inject`) but that way is not very clean.

Comment: @KingKing, I've added a section above describing an approach I've explored, using a class `CommentAlt`.